# What's the base directory for hostPath volumes in Docker for Desktop on Mac?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-for-mac

```
    volumeMounts:
      - name: storage
        mountPath: /foo
  volumes:
    - name: storage
      hostPath:
        path: foo
```

If the value of the `hostPath` is set to a full path, i.e. `/foo/bar/baz`, the directory is created.

However, if it's set to just `foo`, I can't find it anywhere... Where is it located?

Comment: Did you take a look https://timonweb.com/docker/getting-path-and-accessing-persistent-volumes-in-docker-for-mac/ ?

Comment: @Malgorzata it looks to be deprecated already.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Malgorzata well, we can say there is no "base directory for hostPath volumes" at macOS level, but on the VM created by Docker for Desktop. In other words, we can't access these directories unless we get into the VM.

Comment: Can you paste it as an answer, be more visible for community ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is no such thing as a base directory for hostPath volumes at the macOS level.

Docker on Desktop works by provisioning a VM where the containers are run. It's inside this VM where the hostPath is mounted, so, if let's say I mount `/tmp/`, it's the `/tmp` inside such VM and not on macOS.